# Reading binary .SAVE files?

Tags: binary, octave, nano

I was wondering how to open or read a binary file that has been saved in octave, with the extension .SAVE? I have tried opening it with MATLAB, using the 'load' function in octave, but nothing seems to be working. I'm trying to understand someone else's code and they have saved the output of a simulation in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Octave binary format is briefly described in the comments before the function read_binary_data() in load-save.cc.

Are you sure the file is in "Octave binary format". The file ending ".SAVE" can be choosen arbitrary so this could also be CSV, gzipped...

You can run "file yourfile.SAFE" and paste the output or check the first bytes of your file if they are "Octave-1-L" or "Octave-1-B".

If you want to use these files from another program than GNU Octave I would suggest loading it in Octave and safe it in an other format. See  "help save" for a list of supported formats.

**EDIT:**
Because the initial poster asked: Of course you can use GNU Octave from the terminal (no need for the GUI and I don't now to which software part you refer when you are using the phrase "octave GUI", see here [Octave FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#GUI)). Just install it for your used platform [install instructions on wiki.octave.org](http://wiki.octave.org/Main_Page#Installation) and run it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes the first line is "Octave-1-L". Apparently .SAVE format is also associated with the nano text editor, but has this file definitely been saved by octave then rather than nano?

Comment: If the first bytes are "Octave-1-L" it is very likely that it was written with GNU Octave or another program which uses liboctave.

Comment: Ok thanks, so is there a way of opening the file using octave in the terminal? Or do I have to download GNU octave GUI to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Code for reading octave binary save files in python 2/3.

Tested on:

- strings
- single and double precision real and complex floats
- various integer types
- scalar, matrix and array

Unsupported:

- struct
- cell array
- ...

Python code:

```py
# This code is public domain
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    def tostr(s):
        return s.decode('utf8')
    def decode(s, encoding='utf8'):
        return s.decode(encoding)
    STR_ENCODING = 'utf8'
else:
    def tostr(s):
        return s
    def decode(s, encoding='utf8'):
        return unicode(s, encoding)
    STR_ENCODING = None

DATA_TYPES = {
    1: "scalar",
    2: "matrix",
    3: "complex scalar",
    4: "complex matrix",
    5: "old_string",
    6: "range",
    7: "string",
}

TYPE_CODES = {
    0: "u1",
    1: "u2",
    2: "u4",
    3: "i1",
    4: "i2",
    5: "i4",
    6: "f4",
    7: "f8",
    8: "u8",
    9: "i8",
}
DTYPES = {k: np.dtype(v) for k, v in TYPE_CODES.items()}

def loadoct(fd, encoding=STR_ENCODING):
    """
    Read an octave binary file from the file handle fd, returning
    an array of structures.  If encoding is not None then convert
    strings from bytes to unicode.  Default is STR_ENCODING, which
    is utf8 for python 3 and None for python 2, yielding arrays
    of type str in each dialect.
    """
    magic = fd.read(10)
    assert(magic == b"Octave-1-L" or magic == b"Octave-1-B")
    endian = "<" if magic[-1:] == b"L" else ">"
    # Float type is 0: IEEE-LE, 1: IEEE-BE, 2: VAX-D, 3: VAX-G, 4: Cray
    # Not used since Octave assumes IEEE format floats.
    _float_format = fd.read(1)
    len_dtype = np.dtype(endian + "i4")
    def read_len():
        len_bytes = fd.read(4)
        if not len_bytes:
            return None
        return np.frombuffer(len_bytes, len_dtype)[0]
    table = OrderedDict()
    while True:
        name_length = read_len()
        if name_length is None:  # EOF
            break
        name = tostr(fd.read(name_length))
        doc_length = read_len()
        doc = tostr(fd.read(doc_length)) if doc_length else ''
        is_global = bool(ord(fd.read(1)))
        data_type = ord(fd.read(1))
        if data_type == 255:
            type_str = tostr(fd.read(read_len()))
        else:
            type_str = DATA_TYPES[data_type]
        #print("reading", name, type_str)
        if type_str.endswith("scalar"):
            if type_str == "scalar":
                dtype = DTYPES[ord(fd.read(1))]
            elif type_str == "complex scalar":
                _ = fd.read(1)
                dtype = np.dtype('complex128')
            elif type_str == "float complex scalar":
                _ = fd.read(1)
                dtype = np.dtype('complex64')
            else:
                dtype = np.dtype(type_str[:-7])
            dtype = dtype.newbyteorder(endian)
            data = np.frombuffer(fd.read(dtype.itemsize), dtype)
            table[name] = data[0]
        elif type_str.endswith("matrix"):
            ndims = read_len()
            if ndims < 0:
                ndims = -ndims
                dims = np.frombuffer(fd.read(4*ndims), len_dtype)
            else:
                dims = (ndims, read_len())
            count = np.prod(dims)
            if type_str == "matrix":
                dtype = DTYPES[ord(fd.read(1))]
            elif type_str == "complex matrix":
                _ = fd.read(1)
                dtype = np.dtype('complex128')
            elif type_str == "float complex matrix":
                _ = fd.read(1)
                dtype = np.dtype('complex64')
            else:
                dtype = np.dtype(type_str[:-7])
            dtype = dtype.newbyteorder(endian)
            data = np.frombuffer(fd.read(count*dtype.itemsize), dtype)
            # Note: Use data.copy() to make a modifiable array.
            table[name] = data.reshape(dims, order='F')
        elif type_str == "old_string":
            data = fd.read(read_len())
            if encoding is not None:
                data = decode(data, encoding)
            table[name] = data
        elif type_str in ("string", "sq_string"):
            nrows = read_len()
            if nrows < 0:
                ndims = -nrows
                dims = np.frombuffer(fd.read(4*ndims), len_dtype)
                count = np.prod(dims)
                fortran_order = np.frombuffer(fd.read(count), dtype='uint8')
                c_order = np.ascontiguousarray(fortran_order.reshape(dims, order='F'))
                data = c_order.view(dtype='|S'+str(dims[-1]))
                if encoding is not None:
                    data = np.array([decode(s, encoding) for s in data.flat])
                table[name] = data.reshape(dims[:-1])
            else:
                data = [fd.read(read_len()) for _ in range(nrows)]
                if encoding is not None:
                    data = [decode(s, encoding) for s in data]
                table[name] = np.array(data)

        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("unknown octave type "+type_str)
        #print("read %s:%s"%(name, type_str), table[name])
    return table

def _dump(filename, encoding=STR_ENCODING):
    import gzip

    if filename.endswith('.gz'):
        with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
            table = loadoct(fd, encoding)
    else:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
            table = loadoct(fd, encoding)
    for k, v in table.items():
        print(k, v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #_dump(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf8')  # unicode
    #_dump(sys.argv[1], encoding=None)  # bytes
    _dump(sys.argv[1])  # str, encoding=STR_ENCODING
```